# Change WordPress names duplicate titles (url)

Tags: posts, urls, directory

Got a question.
Does anybody know how to change the url a duplicate title creates?

If I create two posts, both named test, the addresses would be  example.com/test and example.com/test-2

I would like it to be named test and test2, without the - sign.
It looks nicer, since the -2, means "duh, you did a duplicate" but if it's called for example manning2 , "ahh, Manning nr 2"

There will be a lot of those, since I'm using the title as users name, and many have the same names ;)

Answer (score 0):

For details please see this answer  : [Remove Dash/Hyphen From Wordpress CustomPosttype Permalink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470077/remove-dash-hyphen-from-wordpress-customposttype-permalink)

In your functions.php :

```
function no_dashes($title) {
    return str_replace('-', '', $title);
}
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'no_dashes' , 9999);
```

For particular type of post :

```
function no_dashes( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type ) {

    if( $post_type == "page" ) {
        $slug = str_replace( '-', '', $slug);
    }
    return $slug;
}
add_filter( "wp_unique_post_slug", "no_dashes", 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Well, that actually only removed so it didn't read the -, when creating a new post, it was still named example-2 instead of example2. I tried the first one..